# How to glue (merge) files Lucene?

Tags: java, spring, lucene

I integrate Apache Lucene into Spring Boot application (this is my first experience) and everything good, but I see a bunch of files - indexes: .cfs .si .cfe; How to combine them and is it necessary to do so, if I plan to reach 1 billion files in the index?

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
    <version>9.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

For add new data to index, I wrote the next simple method:

```java
synchronized public void addToIndex(IndexData data) {
    Document doc = setDocument(data.id, data.body, data.coutry);
    try {
        writer.addDocument(doc);
        writer.commit();
        writer.maybeMerge();
        writer.flush();
        doc.clear();
    } catch (IOException e)
    { e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

This method located in the class singleton with configuration for IndexWriter: `config.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);`
Is it enough to call "maybeMerge()" for Lucene does merge files itself when it is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bottom line:**

If you are not facing a *specific* problem, then there is probably nothing you need to change, regarding how segment merges are automatically managed by Lucene.

---

**More notes:**

Yes, a Lucene index directory will contain "a bunch of files" - see [Apache Lucene - Index File Formats](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene99/package-summary.html#file-names) for an overview.

Groups of related files form [segments](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene99/package-summary.html#Segments), where:

> Each segment is a fully independent index, which could be searched separately.

Segments (and their related files) are **automatically created and merged by Lucene**, as it deems necessary/appropriate, as documents are added to (and removed from) the index. You do not need to take any specific action, unless you are facing a specific situation where a manually triggered merge may be beneficial.

There is a performance cost associated with Lucene needing to search across multiple segments; conversely, there is a performance cost associated with performing a merge. My advice: You should assume Lucene knows best, and leave it to manage its segments itself, unless you are  certain you have a good reason to do otherwise.

For example, see the JavaDoc for [`forceMerge()`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#forceMerge(int)), where it states:

> This is a horribly costly operation, especially when you pass a small maxNumSegments; usually you should only call this if the index is static (will no longer be changed).

For `maybeMerge()`, I'd give the same advice as above: leave it to Lucene, unless you have a very specific reason/problem to intervene. I would absolutely **not** want to call `writer.maybeMerge();` a billion times, on the off-chance that a merge may happen a few of those times.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I want to clarify again: If I don't specify "MergePolicy" anywhere, Lucene to do merge automatically when this needed? If, for example, application will work on the Windows OS, there may be a problem with file limit (65535 files in one folder)?

Comment: "_If I don't specify "MergePolicy" anywhere, Lucene to do merge automatically when this needed?_" - yes, that is correct. Regarding the Windows file limit: I think at this point, you can try for yourself - maybe with a (large-ish) subset of your 1 billion documents. And see how many files you end up with in the index. And then you can force a merge at the very end, to see how the number of files changes (if at all).